# Add NSString to the end of every object in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array like this:

```
self.youtubeVideos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 

                      @"http://example.com/index.php?number=1&keyword=", 
                      @"http://example.com/index.php?number=2&keyword=",

                      nil];
```

I would like to add a NSString called "searchKeyword" to the end of every object in the array.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you store this values in an array? They are basically all the same. You could simply create a string like this with:
`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/index.php?number=%i&keyword=", intValue]`

Comment: I'm a newbie. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a mutable array, then step through and modify each element as you go along.

```
NSMutableArray* fixedUrls = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.youtubeVideos.count];    

for (NSString* url in self.youtubeVideos)
{
    [fixedUrls addObject:[url stringByAppendingString:searchKeyword]];
}

self.youtubeVideos = fixedUrls;
```

Comment: He does not need a mutable array, as he does not append anything to the array. You only need NSMutableArray if you want to change the SIZE of the array not the VALUES in it.

Comment: @gebirgsbaerbel: But you can only change `NSString` values by replacing them with new values, so you need to build a new array containing those new values.

Comment: @gebirgsbaerbel As Jeremy said, dot is starting with an immutable array (NSArray) with immutable values (NSString).  He can can change neither the composition of the array NOR its values, so he needs to build a new array using NSMutableArray, creating new values as he goes along.

Comment: What you say is true, I just wanted to make clear to him that this is not always necesarry only because you want to change values in an array. He seems to be very new to objective-c and I did not want him to have this misconception.

Answer (score 2):

My block-based solution might look a bit overkill, but if you have several of this requirements, it could be helpful:

create a Category on NSArray:

```
@interface NSArray (FunctionalTools)

- (NSArray *)arrayByPerformingBlock:(id  (^)(id element))performBlock;

@end


@implementation NSArray (FunctionalTools)

- (NSArray *)arrayByPerformingBlock:(id  (^)(id element))performBlock 
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id element in self){
            [array addObject:performBlock(element)];
    }
    return array;
}

@end
```

and use it like this:

```
#import "NSArray+FunctionalTools.h"

//....

self.youtubeVideos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                  @"http://example.com/index.php?number=1&keyword=", 
                                  @"http://example.com/index.php?number=2&keyword=",
                                  nil];

self.youtubeVideos = [youtubeVideos arrayByPerformingBlock:^id(id element) { return [element stringByAppendingString:@"KeyWord"];}];
NSLog(@"%@", youtubeVideos);
```

or even

```
self.youtubeVideos = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                      @"http://example.com/index.php?number=1&keyword=", 
                                      @"http://example.com/index.php?number=2&keyword=",
                                      nil] arrayByPerformingBlock:^id(id element) { return [element stringByAppendingString:@"KeyWord"];}];
```

---

I incorporated this example into a [sample project](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/arraytools) I wrote to teach myself block-based techniques to use functional-style programming with Objective-C. Coming from Python I always missed List Comprehension like

```
l = ['aa', 'ab','c','ad','dd']
l = [i+i for i in l if i.startswith('a')]
```

Block-based it looks like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aa", @"ab",@"c",@"ad",@"dd", nil];
array = [array arrayByPerformingBlock:^id(id element) { return [element stringByAppendingString:element]; } 
                  ifElementPassesTest:^BOOL(id element) {return [element hasPrefix:@"a"];}];
```

Comment: That's a neat snippet, tho I'd recommend to consider copying the elements of the original array if you need your own implementation and use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(...))block otherwise.

Comment: @aldi: As I said — It might be overkill, if you just got one array that you need to fill. But on the long run it will help to hide a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

You can append something to an existing NSString with

```
NSString* string1 = @"String1";
NSString* string2 = @"String2";
NSString* string3 = [string1 stringByAppendingString:string2];
```

Note that this will always create a new NSString as NSStrings cannot be changed once they have been created. For this you would need an NSMutableString.

However your strings seem so similar that storing them in an array does not seem logical. If the only difference between the values in your array is an integer you can easily create all of them whenever you want from a template String. For example this will use a templateString and in the next line replace the %i with the integer value 4.

```
NSString* templateString = @"Ich habe %i Punkte";
NSString* scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:templateString, 4];
```

Comment: Thanks for the good ideas on how to do this the right away. I'll use the Array for now, but will look in to this once I ship this early version!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a new array.  You can replace the objects in the mutablearray with the appended string:

```
for(int i=0;i<self.youtubeVideos.count;i++){
    [self.youtubeVideos replaceObjectAtIndex:i 
    withObject:[[self.youtubeVideos objectAtIndex:i]  
    stringByAppendingString:searchKeyword]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
youtubeVideos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: 
                  @"http://example.com/index.php?number=1&keyword=", 
                  @"http://example.com/index.php?number=2&keyword=",
                  nil];

for (NSString *s in youtubeVideos) {
    s = [s stringByAppendingString:@"KEYWORD"];
    // Do something with the new s here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://example.com/index.php?number=1&keyword="],[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://example.com/index.php?number=2&keyword="],nil];
for (NSMutableString *temp in array) {
    [temp appendString:searchKeyword];
}
```